# Is it possible to make external numpad or second keyboard only input to a certain window?

Tags: keyboard, input, numpad

I picked up a external Logitech numpad recently and figured it might be useful to use it for macros.

However, since it's a numpad, every time I will press the button to set off the macro, that number will show up in whatever I'm typing, thus forcing me to backspace.

Is there a way that I can make the input from this numpad be redirected so that only one window actually receives the keystroke?

Comment: It might be possible to map the numpad keys to something else that doesn't print a character (like `esc`, `f1`, `ctrl`, etc) using [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Comment: @Davide Perhaps, but the problem is that the numpad is outputting the same keycode as the numpad on my keyboard does - thus I'd be totally remapping the numpad keycodes, not the external numpad :(

Comment: I guess as a quick, temporary, fix you could turn off `numlock`

Comment: You can use the `evrouter` utility. Its config file can have lines like that: `"Logitech Gaming Mouse G300" "/dev/input/event.*" any key/275 "SHELL/xte 'key e'"`. Which means: when key/275 is pressed on my G300 mouse, it is transformed into 'e' keypress. (keyboards and mice are treated the same; you can notice that it is actually the shell script that does the 'e' keypress, so it can be anything)